# How to convert Object to List<MyClass>?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a generic method that can accept any object, in which, even the object is `List<AnyClass>`.
Something like:

```
public static void MyMethod(object _anyObject)
{

}
```

So in my method it accept the parameter as Object, then I will determine what to do by their type to do

So when I know that's a List type, I want to convert that Object back to `List<AnyClass>`, iternate each object and their propertie

I tried to do:

```
List<object> ObjectList = object as List<object>;
```

But it will return `null`, because the object originally is `List<AnyClass>`

Thanks in advance

================

Edit: Sorry, seems like I haven't make it clear, because I simplifed the problem... 
I means the Object might be:

```
_anyObject = List<Class1>
_anyObject = Class2
_anyObject = DataSet
_anyObject = AnyClass
_anyObject = List<object>
```

So say, the user can even put in a `List<object>`, but each of the object in that list can be different class..That's why I can't use `<T>`.

The original of my problem is:

```
public static void MyMethod(List<object> _anyList)
{

}
```

Then I don't care what they put into the list, even the object in the list contains another object list...

Comment: What does your method do with the passed parameter? I think that's the essential bit of information left out.

Comment: The parameter it should be dataset, class object, or list that contains class object, it is for me to do data mapping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The generic List class implements the non-generic IList interface, so you can say:

```
IList objectList = obj as IList;
```

However, what you're trying to do is generally considered bad practice as it eliminates any semblance of type safety. If you explain in what context you're using this, we might be able to suggest a better alternative, like using a generic method.

Comment: What I am trying to do is accept any class object, dataset, List<anyClass>, to iternate their properties and take their data out for mapping.

Comment: @King: If the calling method knows which object type it has, you should use operator overloading to make a different method for Dataset, List, etc. That way, your compiled code calls the correct version of the method automatically and you don't have to use reflection to figure out what type you're using. However, if all the calling code knows is that it has an "object", I suppose this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Generics` to make use of this

```
public static void myMethod<T>(T object)
{
   T yourObject = object;
   if (yourObject is ICollection)
   {
     //Do your iteration
   }

}
```

Comment: If `T` ends up being `List<AnyClass>` I fail to see how your solution would help the OP traverse the list.

Comment: @KirkWoll because it creates the Object As a `List<AnyClass>` which should inherit from `ICollection` somewhere if I am correct.

Comment: But this is no different than if it *wasn't* a generic method.  There is nothing about the body of your method that is taking advantage of the type argument.  So what is the point?

Comment: Because he can then later infer things about the object without having to always check what type it is.

Comment: please provide an example of such inferrence.

Answer (score 3):

`List<object>` is a different type than e.g. `List<int>`. That's why your cast fails.

Depending on what your goal is, you should choose a different solution. It seems your method needs to be able to handle lists and normal objects.

`List<T>` does implement `IEnumerable`, which allows you to enumerate all elements.

```
public static void MyMethod( object _anyObject )
{
    IEnumerable list = _anyObject as IEnumerable;
    if ( list != null )
    {
        foreach ( var item in list )
        {
            // Do whathever you want.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Probably just a plain object, not a collection.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic method that performs actions on different types, make a real generic method:

```
public static void MyMethod<SomeType>(SomeType _anyObject)
```

Your question indicates that you really want a method to do different operations to different types, instead of the same operation. You might want to reconsider such a design by using method overloads instead.

```
public static void MyMethod(List<AnyClass> list)
public static void MyMethod(int anyInt)
public static void MyMethod(string someString)
```

And so on for the types you want.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should use [method overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspxs) instead of type detection. This will also break your single large method up into smaller, more maintanable methods.

```
public static void MyMethod(List<AnyClass> list)
{
    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        MyMethod(obj);
    }
}

public static void MyMethod(AnyClass single)
{
    //work with single instance    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So in my method it accept the parameter as Object, then I will determine what to do by their type

It sounds like you want to use the `is` keyword:

```
if (_anyObject is List<AnyClass>)
{
    List<AnyClass> list = (List<AnyClass>)_anyObject;
}
else if (_anyObject is ...)
{
}
```

Prefer using method overloads, though.